# openpyxl not saving with nested loops

Tags: python, excel, loops, openpyxl

I am trying translate 10 rows and 10 columns of text in Excel from English to Spanish.
The code below works well for translating the 10 rows in a single column.

```
import openpyxl
from translate import Translator

#open workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Python Translate.xlsx')

#label individual sheets
ws1 = wb['Sheet1']
ws2 = wb['Sheet2']

#start at cell A1
row_loc = 1
column_loc = 1
#record cell values

while row_loc <= 10:

    if ws1.cell(row = row_loc, column = column_loc).value != None:
        text = ws1.cell(row = row_loc, column = column_loc).value


        t = Translator(from_lang='English', to_lang='Spanish')
        translation = t.translate(text)

        ws2.cell(row = row_loc, column = column_loc).value = translation
        wb.save('Python Translate.xlsx')

    row_loc += 1

print("done")
```

However, When I add an additional while loop to cycle through multiple columns the file no longer saves.
I'm new to programming so there could be multiple issues causing my problem.

```
import openpyxl
from translate import Translator

#open workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Python Translate.xlsx')

#label individual sheets
ws1 = wb['Sheet1']
ws2 = wb['Sheet2']

#start at cell A1
row_loc = 1
column_loc = 1
#record cell values

while column_loc <= 10:

    while row_loc <= 10:

        if ws1.cell(row = row_loc, column = column_loc).value != None:
            text = ws1.cell(row = row_loc, column = column_loc).value


            t = Translator(from_lang='English', to_lang='Spanish')
            translation = t.translate(text)

            ws2.cell(row = row_loc, column = column_loc).value = translation
            wb.save('Python Translate.xlsx')

        row_loc += 1

    column_loc += 1

print("done")
```

Comment: What is the issue? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: The issue is that the translated text will not save to columns 2 through 10. Only the column 1 translated text will save. The entire program runs so I believe something is wrong with my "while column_loc" loop. I have not done any debugging.

Comment: _I have not done any debugging._ That should be the first step, no? I recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Was the `<=` part of the problem? If so, don't edit your post to fix it.

Comment: The <= wasn't really part of the original problem, I just reversed the symbol during some trial and error. I will review the debugging posts. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

column_loc is 1 and the outer while loop would only execute while it is >= 10 :)

Edit: This should work now:

```
import openpyxl
from translate import Translator

#open workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Python Translate.xlsx')

#label individual sheets
ws1 = wb['Sheet1']
ws2 = wb['Sheet2']

#start at cell A1
column_loc = 1
#record cell values

while column_loc <= 10:

    row_loc = 1

    while row_loc <= 10:

        if ws1.cell(row = row_loc, column = column_loc).value != None:
            text = ws1.cell(row = row_loc, column = column_loc).value


            t = Translator(from_lang='English', to_lang='Spanish')
            translation = t.translate(text)

            ws2.cell(row = row_loc, column = column_loc).value = translation
            wb.save('Python Translate.xlsx')

        row_loc += 1

    column_loc += 1

print("done")
```

Comment: Not sure how I reversed the symbol, thanks for catching that. It still only appears to cycle through the first column.

Comment: ah you have to reset row_loc to 1 with each new outer loop. that will solve it